# How can you specify a custom GCC/G++ compiler location using Gradle's cpp-library and cpp-application plugins?

Tags: c++, gradle, gcc, g++, toolchain

We need to specify a custom GCC/G++ compiler location using Gradle's `cpp-library` and `cpp-application` plugins. According to the docs [tool chain section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:cpp_supported_tool_chain):

> Linux To build on Linux, install a compatible version of GCC or Clang.
> The C++ plugins will discover GCC or Clang using the system PATH.

Prepending the PATH environment variable with a path to the desired `g++` doesn't seem to get picked by Gradle.

How can you direct Gradle to get GCC/G++ from a custom path?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you check which tool chain is used by Gradle? Have you made sure that Gradle sees the changed `PATH` in general?

Comment: When I run with `--info` it shows the exact command being executed and it is certainly the wrong executable (it uses the system `g++` which my IT department controls). I tested this by adding the path to the executable of `clang` and a different `g++` to the `PATH` environment variable. I've even printed the `PATH` environment variable in the configuration phase and it has the expected path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that this worked:

```
model {
    toolChains {
        gcc(Gcc) {
            path '/custom/path/to/gcc-7.1.0/bin/'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can add a custom toolchain section to the `build.gradle` file, something like:

```
toolChains {
    custom_gcc_toolchain(Gcc) {
        target("<target_platform>") {
            path '<path_to_custom_gcc_folder>'
            cCompiler.executable '<c_compiler_executable>'
            assembler.executable '<assembler_executable>'
            linker.executable '<linker_executable>'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man this was close, I had to do it a little differently as I will post, but thank you.